# Marketing cloud error while calling a journey through API call : 401 : "Not Authorized"

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I have installed a package and added API Integration component, While authenticating through postman am getting the access token with success code 200 OK.
When i tried to do the api call am getting the error 401, Not authorized even with a fresh access token.
I have used the Rest Base URL/interaction/v1/events and
params with content type & Authorization = Bearer space fresh access token

[image: params with content type & Authorization with Bearer space fresh access token]

Please help

Comment: what scope does the package have, and are you setting scope in the token call?

Comment: Hi @EazyE,
I have given all access in the scope of the package, in token call am not setting any scope.

https://mch6zlw14tstgdw8kmyt93q5z7c0.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token

Comment: Hi, can someone guide me?

Comment: then is the token for the same MID the journey is in?